# CSRF Token is not working in STRUTS 1.1

Tags: xml, token, csrf, struts-1, mismatch

In my project , i want to apply CSRF token method.My project uses struts 1.1 framework.the token which is being passed is not validated correctly by the recieving JSP.The link between JSP is done via xml file which is not allowing the Token to pass.Hence recieving Thwarted error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I use **QueryCrypt** for my project. For preventing CSRF.